# Why does my third-party FTP program hang when started from my service?

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2

I have the following function to create a process and wait for its execution:

```
procedure TdmTransfer.ExecNewProcess(ProgramName, aParams: string);
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CreateOK: Boolean;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil,
                            PChar(ProgramName + ' ' + aParams),
                            nil,
                            nil,
                            False,
                            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                            nil,
                            nil,
                            StartInfo,
                            ProcInfo);
  if CreateOK then
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); 
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
end;
```

I'm executing `psftp.exe -b "download.cmd" -pw "password" user@domain.com` which runs fine if I call it from a desktop application.
When I run the code from within a service application the process gets created, but then `psftp.exe` doesn't finish and my service waits indefinitely.

The file "download.cmd" looks like this:

```
lcd download
cd directory
mget ./*.XML
quit
```

What can I do to make it to run inside my service application?

Comment: What user account does your service run under? Does that use account have sufficient rights to do all that it needs to? What diagnostics have you recovered? What is the output of psftp? FWIW you don't need to shell to another process for this. There are delphi sftp libs. Indy 10 can do this I think.

Comment: the service runs under the local system account. I haven't been able to get the ouput from psftp, when running it from the service. I tried adding ` > c:\temp\output.txt` to the commandline, but that did not work

Comment: Can local system see the internet? Why did you decide to run under local system? You know that's bad practise I trust. Redirection using `>` requires a command interpreter. You'll need to set up redirection manually.

Comment: AFAIK Indy only has FTP and TFTP components, but neither FTPS or SFTP

Comment: I just used the default user to run the service. I am currently investigating which user I can use (have to check with IT). Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I think Indy 10 adds support for SFTP.

Comment: Indy 10 supports FTPS (FTP over SSL), but does not support SFTP (FTP over SSH) - or any other SSH-based protocols yet.

Comment: @Gloegg: BTW, you need to close `ProcInfo.hThread` as well, not just `ProcInfo.hProcess` by itself. Otherwise the `psftp` process will not fully exit correctly.